# How to compile Sass/Less in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, compilation, npm, gulp, visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.2.1
- OS Version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Failed to compile Sass/LESS with Node.js v5.0.0 and npm 3.3.6

I followed the instructions as they are from the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/css#_transpiling-sass-and-less-into-css), and before trying to automate the compilation, VS Code shoots this error:

> Failed to launch external program node-sass styles.scss styles.css.
>   spawn node-sass ENOENT

Meanwhile it compiles via terminal, while `npm start` displays this:

> npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-28-generic npm ERR! argv
>   "/home/eljaouhari/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/eljaouhari/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/npm" "start" npm ERR!
>   node v5.0.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6 npm ERR! path
>   /home/eljaouhari/package.json npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2
>   npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/home/eljaouhari/package.json' npm ERR! enoent This is most likely
>   not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm
>   not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/eljaouhari/Desktop/Compile/npm-debug.log

Can I get a solution to compile on save and to automate the compilation ?

Many thanks.

Comment: As I can see from the error there are some files missing.

Comment: My folder is complete, it contains both styles and the json configuration file...And if you're talking about Node.js...What should I do to know what files are missing